# How do I access the elements of an array stored in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, arrays, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Given an array of strings stored within a dictionary, I'd like to access the first element stored in the array. How would I go about doing that?

Here's what I have already written...

```
public IC2Engineering GetReportResultsTableByXPath(string xPath, int rowNumber) {
        WaitForComplete();

        IWebElement table = FindElement(By.XPath(xPath));
        //get an array of rows from the table
        IList<IWebElement> table_rows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
        //store the row data 
        IList<IWebElement> row_data = table_rows[rowNumber].FindElements(By.XPath("td"));

        int col_num;
        col_num = 0;
        foreach (IWebElement cell in row_data) {

            Console.WriteLine("col #" + col_num + ": " + row_data[col_num].Text.ToString());
            col_num++;
        }

        return this;
    }
```

So I know that the strings are being stored properly, because the data written to the console output is correct.

How can I store the data from each one of those outputs into it's own separate "spot" in a SharedProperty Dictionary called "TableRowData"?

And after storing those outputs into their own location within the dictionary, how can I access that first entry in the dictionary?

I have a strong feeling that the code I am looking for must execute within the `foreach` loop, but I am can not figure out how to do that...

Comment: It's hard to know for sure because your code uses neither arrays nor dictionaries.  Also, `SeleniumUITests.SharedProperties["ReportRowData"]` is a string so it's not clear what you mean by the "first element".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, the problem is here:

```
SeleniumUITests.SharedProperties["ReportRowData"] = row_data.ToString();
```

You are storing the "array" (really a `List<T>`) as a *string* in the dictionary, not the array itself.  It seems like you want:

```
SeleniumUITests.SharedProperties["ReportRowData"] = row_data;
Console.WriteLine(SeleniumUITests.SharedProperties["ReportRowData"][0]);
```

Comment: I previously tried using `SeleniumUITests.SharedProperties["ReportRowData"] = row_data;` and am getting a syntax error because I can't convert a type of `IWebElement` to a `String`

Comment: I believe that I have to learn how to properly use Dictionary datatype.

Thanks for the help D Stanley.

Comment: It sounds like you have a dictionary whose values are of type `string`.  There's no practical way to store a collection of custom types in a string.  So maybe `SharedProperties` isn't the right place to store that?

Comment: Hi Stanley, I edited my original question to be more useful. 

I have a table data row. For each column, I'd like to store the data for that column in it's own spot in a Dictionary. 

And then after creating that dictionary, I'd like to then access the first element in said dictionary. 

Is that possible?